# send xml file to http using python

Tags: python, xml, http

how can i send an xml file on my system to an http server using python standard library??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import urllib

URL = "http://host.domain.tld/resource"
XML = "<xml />"

parameter = urllib.urlencode({'XML': XML})
```

a)  using HTTP POST

```
response = urllib.urlopen(URL, parameter)
print response.read()
```

b) using HTTP GET

```
response = urllib.urlopen(URL + "?%s" % parameter)
print response.read()
```

That would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that through a standard http post request.