# Send XML using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020979/send-xml-file-to-http-using-python) I tried sending a XML file to my web service using GET:

```
import urllib
from createfile import XML


URL = "http://http://localhost:8080/mywebservice

parameter = urllib.urlencode({'XML': XML})

response = urllib.urlopen(URL + "?%s" % parameter)

print response.read()
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\testing_workspace\http tester\src\Main.py", line 15, in <module>
    response = urllib.urlopen(URL + "?%s" % parameter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 331, in open_http
    h = httplib.HTTP(host)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1047, in __init__
    self._setup(self._connection_class(host, port, strict))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 681, in __init__
    self._set_hostport(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 706, in _set_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: ''
```

But if I use POST method described in that link, it works good, my problem is that I need to use GET, so why I am getting thoose errors ?

```
response = urllib.urlopen(URL, parameter)  // this works
```

Comment: The URL you have shown is bad; there is one `http://` bit too many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending a XML file through a GET request is bare nonsense.

Use *POST* instead.